# Modify width of Push Panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've seen other examples that looked like they should fix this problem for me (E.G. [Change the width of the JQM panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488525/change-the-width-of-the-jqm-panels)) but they don't seem to work like they do in the posted jsfiddles.  I'm not sure if it's a difference in jquery mobile versions ... but I'm hoping someone could help me out.

If you look at http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel-swipe-open/#demo-page ... what I'm trying to do is make the right-hand slide out panel larger.  Technically, making the panel itself larger is not hard but getting the panels on top of it to slide far enough is causing me fits.

I've downloaded the source and then simply included the following CSS:

```
.ui-panel
{
    width: 300px !important;
}


.ui-panel.ui-panel-position-right {
    width: 300px !important;
}

.ui-panel.ui-panel-closed {
    width: 0;
}


.ui-panel-position-right {
    right: 300px !important;
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-overlay, 
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0) !important;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0) !important;
    transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0) !important;
}


.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-right.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open, 
.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right.ui-panel-content-wrap-open, 
.ui-panel-dismiss-position-right.ui-panel-dismiss-open {
    left: 300px !important;
    right: 300px !important;
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-right.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-reveal, 
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-right.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-push, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right.ui-panel-content-wrap-open.ui-panel-content-wrap-display-reveal, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right.ui-panel-content-wrap-open.ui-panel-content-wrap-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0) !important;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0) !important;
    transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

But, alas, to no avail.  The right-hand panel is larger (you can tell because you can't see all the text) but the "content" only slides over the same amount it always has

I am working with JQM 1.4.2

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure whether this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567884/how-can-i-display-my-page-to-be-visible-partially-on-left-when-the-panel-scroll/20574203#20574203

Comment: I'm afraid not ... overlay panels are easier to deal with because the existing content on the page don't have to change.  In the case of the Push, the hardest part seems to be with handling what's already there ... and then opening up the new panel.